# PostgreSQL DATE_TRUNC by 2 Weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like this in `PostgreSQL`:

| Date | CustID |
| --- | --- |
| 05-04-2021 | 001 |
| 10-04-2021 | 002 |
| 12-04-2021 | 003 |
| 19-04-2021 | 001 |
| 20-04-2021 | 002 |
| 22-04-2021 | 003 |

and I want to make it something like this:

| Date | CustID |
| --- | --- |
| 05-04-2021 | 001 |
| 05-04-2021 | 002 |
| 05-04-2021 | 003 |
| 19-04-2021 | 001 |
| 19-04-2021 | 002 |
| 19-04-2021 | 003 |

usually, I'm using `date_trunc('week', Date)` but I don't know what to use if its 2 weeks

Comment: Is this MySQL or PostgresSQL?

Comment: its using PostgreSQL

Comment: Please don't add tags that are not relevant to the question.

Comment: *DATE_TRUNC by 2 Weeks* What weeks do you mean? `EXTRACT(WEEK FROM "Date")`? Take `date`. Substract its `dow` days. Get its `week` and substract 7 days if it is odd. Adjust to the first day of the week if needed.

Comment: i want to trunc the date by 2 weeks not weekly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In existing versions of Postgres, you can use arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (first_week + ((date - first_week::date) / 14)*14 * interval '1 day')::date as biweek
from (select t.*,
             min(date_trunc('week', date)) over () as first_week
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=13bb970e818196fb7aee269994e6ef07) is a db<>fiddle.

The subquery is not strictly needed, but it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You could upgrade to PostgreSQL v14 or newer and use the [`date_bin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function:

```
SELECT date_bin('2 weeks', "date"::timestamp, '2021-01-11')::date,
       custid
FROM mytable;
```

2021-01-11 is a random Monday.